# How to quote unquoted attributes with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Is there an easy way to change a string like `"DIV class=demo id=3"`
to: `"DIV class='demo' id='3'"`?

I am planning to write a recursive function. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to add single quotes around every unquoted value or just `class` and `id`?

Comment: Hi there! Never use regex to parse html. Everybody on SO is going to hate you otherwise. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags   good luck :)

Comment: Yes Abe, want to add single quotes around every unquoted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\b\w*=)(\w*\b)", @"$1'$2'");
```

This replaces any `alphanumericword=alphanumericword` with `alphanumericword='alphanumericword'`

But this might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: Input text : <div name=bala id=3>dfdfd<div name=bala test='test' id=3>dfdfd</div></div>                                                              Output text <div name='bala' id='3'>dfdfd<div name='bala' test='test' id='3'>dfdfd</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Since title has nothing to do with question I'd advice unrelated thing too :)

Do not use IE7 mode for your web page and you will get innerHTML formatted properly the way you expect.

Comment: Actually i am getting this data from a service. But i need to load to the XMLDocument where it should be properly formatted with quotes. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Your answer is being discussed on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321395/what-should-i-do-with-answers-that-try-to-solve-the-problem-without-answering-th)

Answer (score 0):

find this

```
/(<[^>]+?=)([^"'\s][^\s>]+)/gi
```

replace with this

```
$1'$2'
```

note this has worked for years for me until youtube started putting white space in their links!!  Bad youtube!!